# Не пришли или не пришло?

Tags: согласование

Как вернее будет составить предложение: пятеро учеников не пришли в школу, или пятеро учеников не пришло в школу? Хотелось бы понять логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если интересует только количество, то *пятеро учеников не пришло в школу*, если интересуют личности и Вы видите их каждого в отдельности, то *пятеро учеников не пришли в школу.*

Правила согласования сказуемого с числительными

> Имя числительное, в отличие от других имен (существительного и
> прилагательного), лишено признаков числа. Иными словами, если
> существительные могут иметь формы единственного и множественного числа
> (книга – книги), то числительные не имеют таких форм (ср.: два,
> пятеро, сто пятьдесят). По этой причине с числительным собственно
> «согласование» сказуемого по форме числа принципиально невозможно.
> **Форма сказуемого единственного или множественного числа выбирается
> говорящим произвольно.**
>
> При постановке сказуемого в ед. ч. прошедшего
> времени сказуемое принимает форму среднего рода: пятьдесят человек
> пришло на лекцию, в ДТП погибло два человека; открылось десять новых
> магазинов и т. п.
>
> Хотя форма сказуемого не регламентируется жестко,
> существует ряд факторов, способствующих употреблению формы
> единственного или множественного числа. **На постановку сказуемого в
> форму единственного числа влияет стремление автора текста обратить
> внимание читателей на пассивность подлежащего, совместность действия
> действующих лиц, а также на количество, названное в подлежащем.**
> Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться употреблением в качестве
> сказуемых глаголов со значением бытия, наличия: быть существовать,
> иметься и др. В результате урагана упало двадцать деревьев. На лекцию
> пришло именно пятьдесят человек, а не пятьдесят два. У
> существительного имеется двенадцать падежных форм.
>
> **Факторы,
> способствующие употреблению формы множественного числа сказуемого,
> противоположны: значение раздельности действия,  акцент на активности
> лиц, названных в подлежащем, стремление автора обратить внимание на
> действие (характеристику), а не на количество.**  Восемь студентов уже
> защитили дипломные работы. Сто аспирантов пишут диссертации (т. е.
> каждый пишет собственную работу).
>
> Кроме этого следует запомнить, что:
> • Числительные, оканчивающиеся на один, обычно требуют формы
> единственного числа сказуемого: В институт поступил пятьдесят один
> абитуриент. Но: Пятьдесят один участник обсудили проблему на круглом
> столе (глагол обсудить означает совместное действие и не может быть
> употреблен в форме ед. ч.). • Форма множественного числа сказуемого
> используется, если подлежащее конкретизируется определением в форме
> множественного числа, например словами все, эти, данные, любые и др.
> Все пятьдесят восемь абитуриентов поступили в институт. Васины
> пятьдесят рублей были немедленно потрачены. Эти двое явились с
> опозданием, остальные пятеро прибыли вовремя. •   Если числительное
> употребляется в качестве подлежащего без зависимых слов (обозначая
> число как математическое понятие), то оно согласуется со сказуемым в
> форме единственного числа: Сто пятьдесят делится на тридцать без
> остатка.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=64