# Как правильно согласовать число глагола?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Как правильно согласовать глагол?
**Здесь проживает (или проживают) около 340 бездомных детей.**

Comment: Такой вопрос был буквально вчера: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/453737/181932. И так, и так можно.

Answer (score 1):

**Здесь проживает около 340 бездомных детей.**

Я бы выбрала единственное число глагола (действие у детей одно на всех — жить, проживать).

Значение единого целого, предполагающее употребление сказуемого в форме единственного числа, реализуется  при обозначении **приблизительного количества**, которое выражается путем постановки существительного перед числительным (*На экскурсии присутствовало человек тридцать.*) или с помощью слов ***около, больше, меньше, более, менее*** (*На экскурсии присутствовало около тридцати человек. К новому учебному году откроется более сорока школ.*).

[Книга о грамматике](https://cdn2.arhivurokov.ru/multiurok/2017/08/10/s_598cb60e2615e/phpmrpEwp_VELICHKO-KIGA-O-GRANNATIKE-NGU.pdf) (под ред. А. В. Величко)
"Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого при выражении подлежащего числительными и количественными сочетаниями" (стр. 33)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки не будет ни в том ни в другом случае.

Однако в общих правилах "Единственное и множественное число сказуемого" (ПИСЬМОВНИК Грамоты.ру) выделен пункт

[Согласование сказуемого при обозначении подлежащим приблизительного количества](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

> При подлежащем – количественном сочетании со значением
> приблизительности предпочитается форма единственного числа сказуемого:
> ***Откроется несколько** новых **школ**. На земле **живет более трех миллиардов людей**.*  Но: *Лишь **несколько студентов смогли решить** эту
> задачу;* форма множественного числа сказуемого обусловлена
> «активностью» действующих лиц, названных подлежащим.

Подчеркну: "проживать" - пассивное действие, так что речь может идти только о единственном числе: *прожива**е**т.*